# Using the setInterval function to create an animation in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to use the setInterval function to create an animation in JavaScript but I have encountered a problem.

I used:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8" />
 <title>Document</title>
 <style>
 .main{
  width:80%;
  margin:auot;
  text-align: center;
 }
 p{
  position:absolute;
  top:0px;
 }
 </style> 
</head>
<body>
 <div class="main">
  <h1>bianti</h1>
 </div>
 <p id="mydiv">ssss</p>

 <script type="text/javascript" >
  var obj=document.getElementById('mydiv');
  function changeStyle(){
   obj.style.top=parseInt(obj.style.top)+200+'px'
  }
  setInterval(changeStyle,1000);
 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

but it doesn't work. I change the code, using the inline css and replacing the embedded css. Then it works but I don't know why.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8" />
 <title>Document</title>
 <style>
 .main{
  width:80%;
  margin:auot;
  text-align: center;
 }
 </style> 
</head>
<body>
 <div class="main">
  <h1>bianti</h1>
 </div>
 <p id="mydiv" style="position:absolute;top:0;">ssss</p>

 <script type="text/javascript" >
  var obj=document.getElementById('mydiv');
  function changeStyle(){
   obj.style.top=parseInt(obj.style.top)+200+'px'
  }
  setInterval(changeStyle,1000);
 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: To make smooth animations you probably want to use `jqueryui`.

Comment: it is animating properly. because you are writing code for simple css top change in javascript. not any smooth effect. if you want then you will need to go for another path.

Comment: CSS rules do not _create_ style attributes on DOM nodes.

Answer (score 5):

Just to answer the question:

> but it doesn't work

The [`parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) was not returning an integer value as `style.top` was empty.

Sample code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <title>Document</title>
  <style>
    .main {
      width: 80%;
      margin: auot;
      text-align: center;
    }
    
    p {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="main">
    <h1>bianti</h1>
  </div>
  <p id="mydiv">ssss</p>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    var obj = document.getElementById('mydiv');

    function changeStyle() {
      var init = 0;
      if (obj.style.top) {
        init = parseInt(obj.style.top);
      }
      obj.style.top = init + 200 + 'px'
    }
    setInterval(changeStyle, 1000);
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I don't understand ,if the parseInt was not returning an integer value as style.top was empty. why the second code can work, its style.top was also empty

Comment: In the second code, you have `style="position:absolute;top:0;"`, but not in the first. So, you would have a valid `top` value to work with and `parseInt` wouldn't return `NaN` which will be the case with the first code.

Comment: my first code also set the position and top  ,but it in the embedded css
p{
     position: absolute;
      top: 0px;
}

Comment: i use cosole.log(obj.style.top) to test ,but why fisrt code's top get empty and the second code get 0xp?

Comment: In the first code, you have set style via _CSS_, and in the second you used _in-line style_. In the first code, you cannot access `style.top` via DOM as the CSS properties doesn't `reflect` those properties on **DOM**

Answer (score 0):

**This will work.** In your css make it #mydiv {... }

```
 var obj=document.querySelector('#mydiv');
 function changeStyle(){
    obj.style.top+= "200px";
 }
 setInterval(changeStyle,1000);
```

Answer (score -1):

Try use this css

```
#mydiv {
        transition: all 300ms;
    }
```

example - https://jsfiddle.net/grinmax_/wnvnjmtr/